# use of asm volatile in Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux

I am reading the Linux kernel code, and I have a hard time understanding a macro involving asm volatile.

There is a macro ***[current](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.11/source/include/asm-x86_64/current.h#L15)*** which returns a pointer to the currently running process. I want to understand how the code works. I am stuck at the [line](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.11/source/arch/x86_64/kernel/asm-offsets.c#L41)

```
ENTRY(pcurrent)
```

Here ENTRY is defined as

```
#define ENTRY(entry) DEFINE(pda_ ## entry, offsetof(struct x8664_pda, entry))
```

DEFINE is defined as

```
#define DEFINE(sym, val) \
        asm volatile("\n->" #sym " %0 " #val : : "i" (val))
```

As far as I know, the '\n' in the definition of DEFINE may be used to separate assembly instructions, but I do not know why there is a **'->'**. If possible, could anyone also explain the logic behind the implementation?